# Add "success message" after acount created on WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce, message

On checkout, a user has the option to create an account.

If he creates an account, he will get a confirmation e-mail.

I am trying to implement a success message immediately after account creation, that says “Your account was created please check your email”.

Thanks

Comment: Probably best by using one of the hooks woocommerce provides - `woocommerce_created_customer` sounds promising. (Sadly, the documentation https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html is not very explicit about when the hooks are invoked, so you’ll have to try and guess what might fit by hook name, and then try and see if that can be used to achieve what is desired.)